# Number each line of text in rmarkdown PDF

Tags: latex, knitr, r-markdown

I am writing a document that is being knit into a pdf and I need each line to be numbered so that reviewers can refer back to particular sentences. I have found some reading on numbering code chunks, but how about just text?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Add the `lineno` package to the header.  Here is an example .Rmd file

```
---
title: "Line Number Example"
header-includes:
   - \usepackage{lineno}
   - \linenumbers
output:
   pdf_document
---

There is a lot of text that goes here.  There is a lot of text that goes here.
There is a lot of text that goes here.  There is a lot of text that goes here.
There is a lot of text that goes here.  There is a lot of text that goes here.
There is a lot of text that goes here.  There is a lot of text that goes here.
There is a lot of text that goes here.  There is a lot of text that goes here.
There is a lot of text that goes here.  There is a lot of text that goes here.
There is a lot of text that goes here.  There is a lot of text that goes here.
There is a lot of text that goes here.  There is a lot of text that goes here.
There is a lot of text that goes here.  There is a lot of text that goes here.
There is a lot of text that goes here.  There is a lot of text that goes here.  


There is a lot of text that goes here.  There is a lot of text that goes here.
There is a lot of text that goes here.  There is a lot of text that goes here.
There is a lot of text that goes here.  There is a lot of text that goes here.
There is a lot of text that goes here.  There is a lot of text that goes here.
There is a lot of text that goes here.  There is a lot of text that goes here.
There is a lot of text that goes here.  There is a lot of text that goes here.
There is a lot of text that goes here.  There is a lot of text that goes here.
There is a lot of text that goes here.  There is a lot of text that goes here.
There is a lot of text that goes here.  There is a lot of text that goes here.
There is a lot of text that goes here.  There is a lot of text that goes here.  
There is a lot of text that goes here.  There is a lot of text that goes here.
There is a lot of text that goes here.  There is a lot of text that goes here.
There is a lot of text that goes here.  There is a lot of text that goes here.
There is a lot of text that goes here.  There is a lot of text that goes here.
There is a lot of text that goes here.  There is a lot of text that goes here.
There is a lot of text that goes here.  There is a lot of text that goes here.
There is a lot of text that goes here.  There is a lot of text that goes here.
There is a lot of text that goes here.  There is a lot of text that goes here.
There is a lot of text that goes here.  There is a lot of text that goes here.
There is a lot of text that goes here.  There is a lot of text that goes here.
```

And the result looks like this:
[image]

Comment: The lineno package is not available for more recent versions of R. Are you aware of other workarounds?

Comment: The [lineno](https://ctan.org/pkg/lineno?lang=en) is a TeX package, not an R package.